# Effectively storing bit indexes

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, bit

I want to store certain indexes in a sequence of bits. The number of bits are powers of
two and it is safe to assume that maximum index to be 255 (starting index is 0). Earlier i was storing every index as an integer. But that occupies too much of memory.

I want to use something like masks.

ex: If i want to store the indexes 0,3,5 then i store 101001 i.e. 41 as an integer.

The problem is that maximum index that i have is 255 and using above technique i can store indexes
only till 64(using 64 bit integer). Is there any other way i can do this??

Thanks :-)

Comment: What language are using?

Comment: Use an array of ulongs then. Simple. Or BitArray, but it's a little slow.

Answer (score 1):

.NET has a built-in class for this kind of thing: [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

This will let you store a string of bits (in the form of bools) efficiently.

You can perform bitwise operations on `BitArray`s with the `And`, `Or`, `Xor`, and `Not` methods.

You can initialize a `BitArray` with bools, bytes, or ints. For example, you can initialize it with `00101100` like this:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new byte[] { 0x2C }); // 0x2C == 00101100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 bit indexes for every bit index.
Pratically with 10 bits (index from 1 to 10, set bits 0, 4, 8):

Single index:

```
i = 0100010001
Index1 = i
```

Two combined indexes:

```
i1 = 01000
i2 = 10001
Index2 = [i1, i2];
Index2.fragment_length = 5
```

Array 
In pseudocode, to retrieve or set a bit

```
set(Index, bit) {
    fragment = quotient(bit, Index.flagment_length); //quotient = integer division
    bit_index = module(bit, Index.flagment_length); //index of the bit in the fragment
    set(Index[fragment], bit-or(Index[Fragment], bit-shift-left(1 << bit_index))); //Set the bit indexes vector fragment with or-ing the appropriate bitmask
}

get(Index, bit) {
    fragment = quotient(bit, Index.flagment_length); //quotient = integer division
    bit_index = module(bit, Index.flagment_length); //index of the bit in the fragment
    if (get(Index[fragment], bit-and(Index[Fragment], bit-shift-left(1 << bit_index))) > 0) then true else false; //Get the bit indexes vector fragment bit with and-ing the appropriate bitmask and return true or false
}
```

I hope to have understood your requirements!

Answer (score 0):

***In java the bit indexing made easy as the following little tutorial...***

This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each component of the bit set has a boolean value. The bits of a BitSet are indexed by nonnegative integers. Individual indexed bits can be examined, set, or cleared. One BitSet may be used to modify the contents of another BitSet through logical AND, logical inclusive OR, and logical exclusive OR operations.

By default, all bits in the set initially have the value false.

Every bit set has a current size, which is the number of bits of space currently in use by the bit set. Note that the size is related to the implementation of a bit set, so it may change with implementation. The length of a bit set relates to logical length of a bit set and is defined independently of implementation.

Unless otherwise noted, passing a null parameter to any of the methods in a BitSet will result in a NullPointerException. A BitSet is not safe for multithreaded use without external synchronization.